# Creating New Tags: Old Questions

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

If I create a new tag (like [edim-witnesses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edim-witnesses)), should I go back to other questions that dealt with this (e.g. [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/831/can-a-person-who-killed-by-accident-subsequently-be-a-witness) and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/why-dosnt-he-get-kasher-zamam)), and add them?

On one hand, it makes sense to. On the other hand, I will be flooding the home page with older questions.

Comment: Side comment, I think its better to make the tag `[edim]`, and possibly have a synonym `[witnesses]`, rather than persist the old custom of shoving several translations into a single tag.

Comment: @AviD or witnesses with side of edim? How to decide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IMO](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IMO) yes. I wish an edit that only adds tags didn't push a question to the top of the default list, but, in any event, if someone wants only new questions, [there's a tab for that](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest).

Answer (score 4):

As long as it passes the usual threshholds of validity and salience for tagging, I think you should tag it, even if it is old.

Being pushed to the top is a feature, not a bug. (0therwise you would have tagged it as such!) It shows which questions have had the most recent activity for the scrutiny/review of everyone else. Retagging, for example, could go unnoticed and unchecked if not pushed to the top, just like more substantial in-question edits.